# Cannot hear test sound on Google Hangouts

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, google-hangouts

When I'm in the Google Hangouts setting panel and I play the test sound, I do not hear anything. It says "Playing..." but no sound arrives to my ears.

- My computer is running Win 7 Professional SP1, with up-to-date updates.
- I have a USB sound interface (Focusrite), which is selected as my default playback device in Windows sound settings. Driver is up-to-date. I use a USB webcam as microphone interface, selected as the Default Recording device in Windows settings.
- I have both tried with headphones plugged in the interface and plugged directly in the computer (interface disconnected).
- I get sound when I play videos on Youtube, or a local media file (both with USB interface and directly plugged in).
- I can connect to people with Hangouts video calls. They can see me and hear me. I can see them, but not hear them.

Any help appreciated, the Google Hangouts troubleshoot is not very helpful!

Comment: try choosing usb sound interface as "default communications device" from playback devices panel.

Comment: Thank you Mustafa, maybe I'm wrong, but I thought Default device includes "Default communications device" anyway? Anyway, I tried but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem with Hangouts on my Mac, which I resolved by disabling the "Disable HTML5 Autoplay" Chrome extension.  So, for your situation:

disable all extensions except for Hangouts itself, and if that fixes
the problem, re-enable them one at a time until you find the one at fault.

(Unfortunately, security extensions are the ones most likely to break web apps, but many have customizable blocklists.)

Comment: Can someone please let me know why they downvoted this, so I can give better answers in the future?